Applicability of the error analysis of HHL algorithm assuming spectrum could contain negative and positive eigenvalues
I have a question concerning the applicability of the error analysis of the HHL algorithm , specifically the QPE subroutine. The authors state that they assume all the eigenvalues lie between $[\frac{1}{\kappa},1]$ where $\kappa$ is the condition number, which refers to the ratio of the largest singular value to smallest singular value. For the case of a Hermitian matrix, this reduces to
$$
 \kappa =\max_{i,j} \frac{|\lambda_{i}|}{|\lambda_{j}|}
$$
Under the assumption that all the eigenvalues are positive, I understand it is trivial to condense the spectrum into the interval $[\frac{1}{\kappa},1]$ (1) by just scaling the system by:
$$
\frac{1}{|\lambda_{max}|}A\vec{x} = \frac{1}{|\lambda_{max}|}\vec{b}
$$
Furthermore if all the eigenvalues are negative we can just solve the system instead so that condition (1) is still satisfied.
$$
-\frac{1}{|\lambda_{max}|}A\vec{x} = -\frac{1}{|\lambda_{max}|}\vec{b}
$$
Either of these perturbations/scalings can be done ahead of time are in the parameter selection of $t_{0}$ for $e^{\frac{iA t_{0}}{T}}$ in the QPE subroutine.
I am aware of various methods for faithfully extracting negative and positive eigenvalues. from the QPE step assuming the absolute values of all the eigenvalues lies in the range $[\frac{1}{\kappa},1]$ using Two's complement etc.
However, my question is I am not aware of any error analysis for the HHL algorithm that relaxes the assumption about positivity of the spectrum. I understand how if all the eigenvalues are negative this can be easily dealt with, however I am not aware of any transformation or method to transform the matrix to have a positive spectrum so that the error complexity will thus apply. Any help or clarification on this matter would be greatly appreciated. To clarify, I know of schemes that relax this assumption, I don't know of error analysis of these schemes such that they coincide with the original HHL error analysis.
Best,
Eddie

You can always add a constant to your matrix, for shifting the spectrum to lie in [0,1). Adding the identity does not affect the complexity of the Hamiltonian dynamics within the QPE, as it simply adds a global phase. It affects the implementation of the eigenvalue inversion block in the HHL algorithm, but should not affect its complexity.
In more detail,

You can make the transformation $A' = \alpha A+\beta I$, such that the eigenvalues of A' are in $[1/\kappa,1]$ (the relation between the eigenvalues of the matrices is simply $\lambda' = \alpha\lambda +\beta$).
The complexity of the QPE does not change (adds $\exp(i\beta I)$ terms).
In the eigenvalue inversion, instead of encoding $1/x$ in the amplitudes you need to encode $\frac{1}{\alpha^{-1}(x-\beta)}$ (should be as difficult).

In summary, the above modifications map to the original problem, and thus the formulation stays with the same complexity.

Thank you for that, that is really helpful! I don't know why I didn't think of that before. Best, Eddie.
